# Matplotlib - Plot histogram truncate bar

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I am plotting a histogram of observed values from a population against a normal distribution (dervived from the mean and std of the sample).  The sample has an unusual number of observations of value 0 (not to be confused with "NAN").   As a result, the graph of the two does not show clearly.

[image]

How can I best truncate the one bar in the histogram to allow the rest of the plot to fill the frame?

Comment: Do you want to truncate the 0 value observation to be the same of the normal one?

Comment: Are you trying to remove the one outlier value?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to truncate the bar and label it with the value/count, but truncating the bar alone would  be sufficient for my purposes....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set the y-limit to be 0.00004? Then you can analyze better the plot.

```
axes = plt.gca()
axes.set_xlim([xmin,xmax])
axes.set_ylim([ymin,ymax])
```